# Having full atomicity against all the threads without impacting performance or throughputs

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have a list of hostnames which I am supposed to make a call by making the proper URL from it. Let's say if I have four hostname (hostA, hostB, hostC, hostD) in the linked list -

- Execute hostA url and if hostA is UP then get the data and return the response.
- But if hostA is down, then add hostA to block list of hostnames and make sure no other thread is making call to hostA. And then try executing hostB url and return the response back.
- But if hostB is also down, then add hostB to block list of hostnames as well and repeat the same thing.

Also, I have a background thread running in my application which will have the list of block hostnames (from my another service) which we are not supposed to make a call but it runs every 10 minutes so the list of block hostnames will get updated only after 10 minutes so if any block list of hostnames is present, then I won't make a call to that hostname from the main thread and I will try making a call to another hostname. Meaning if `hostA` is blocked, then it will have `hostA` present in the block list but if `hostA` is up, then that list will not have `hostA` in it.

Below is my background thread code which gets the data from my service URL and keep on running every 10 minutes once my application has started up. It will then parse the data coming from the URL and store it in a `ClientData` class variable -

**TempScheduler**

```
public class TempScheduler {

    // .. scheduledexecutors service code to start the background thread

    // call the service and get the data and then parse 
    // the response.
    private void callServiceURL() {
        String url = "url";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        parseResponse(response);
    }

    // parse the response and store it in a variable
    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        
        // get the block list of hostnames
        Map<String, List<String>> coloExceptionList = gson.fromJson(response.split("blocklist=")[1], Map.class);
        List<String> blockList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : coloExceptionList.entrySet()) {
            for(String hosts : entry.getValue()) {
                blockList.add(hosts);
            }
        }
        
        // store the block list of hostnames which I am not supposed to make a call
        ClientData.replaceBlockedHosts(blockList);
    }
}
```

Below is my `ClientData` class. `replaceBlockedHosts` method will only be called by a background thread meaning only one writer. But `isHostBlocked` method will be called by main application threads multiple times to check whether a particular hostname is blocked or not. And also `blockHost` method will be called from `catch block` multiple times to add the down host in the `blockedHosts` list so I need to make sure all the read threads can see the consistent data and are not making calls to that down host, instead they are making calls to next host in the hostnames linked list.

**ClientData**

```
public class ClientData {

    // .. some other variables here which in turn used to decide the  list of hostnames
    
    private static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> blockedHosts = 
            new AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>());

    public static boolean isHostBlocked(String hostName) {
        return blockedHosts.get().containsKey(hostName);
    }

    public static void blockHost(String hostName) {
        blockedHosts.get().put(hostName, hostName);
    }

    public static void replaceBlockedHosts(List<String> hostNames) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> newBlockedHosts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (String hostName : hostNames) {
            newBlockedHosts.put(hostName, hostName);
        }
        blockedHosts.set(newBlockedHosts);
    }
}
```

And below is my main application thread code in which I have list of hostnames which I am supposed to make a call. If the `hostname` is null or in the block list category, then I won't make a call to that particular hostname and will try next hostname in the list.

```
@Override
public DataResponse call() {

    List<String> hostnames = new LinkedList<String>();
    
    // .. some separate code here to populate the hostnames list
    // from ClientData class
    
    for (String hostname : hostnames) {     

        // If host name is null or host name is in block list category, skip sending request to this host
        if (hostname == null || ClientData.isHostBlocked(hostname)) {
            continue;
        }
    
        try {
            String url = generateURL(hostname);

            response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

            break;
        } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            // add host to block list, 
            // Is this call fully atomic and thread safe for blockHost method 
            // in ClientData class?
            ClientData.blockHost(hostname);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need to make a call to the hostname whenever it is down from the main thread. And my background thread gets these detail from one of my service as well, whenever any server is down, it will have the list of hostnames which are block hosts and whenever they are up, that list will get updated.

And also, whenever any `RestClientException` is being thrown, I will add that hostname in the `blockedHosts` concurrentmap since my background thread is running every 10 minutes so that map won't have this hostname until 10 minutes is done. And whenever this server came back up, my background will update this list automatically.

Is my above code for block list of hostnames is fully atomic and thread safe? Because what I want is - If hostA is down, then no other thread should make a call to hostA until the blocked host list is updated.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap in AtomicReference? Why not just write to it as you go along? You also have a local concurrent map to go along with it as well, which *might* get optimized away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that communication with other hosts takes considerably more time than anything you are doing in your threads. I wouldn't worry about atomic operations in this case.

Let's say we have the threads `t1` and `t2`. `t1` sends a requests to `hostA` and waits for a response. When the timeout is reached, a `RestClientException` will be thrown. Now there is a very tiny timespan between throwing the exception and adding that host to the list of blocked host. It *could* happen that `t2` tries to sends a request to `hostA` in this moment, before the host is blocked - but it is way more likely that `t2` already send it during the long time `t1` was waiting for a response, which you can't prevent.

You can try to set reasonable timeouts. Of course there are other types of errors that don't await a timeout, but even those way more time than handling the exception.

Using a `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe and should be enough to keep track of blocked hosts.

An `AtomicReference` by itself doesn't do much unless you use methods like `compareAndSet`, so the call is not atomic (but as explained above doesn't need to be in my opinion). If you  really want to block a host immediately after you got an exception, you should use some kind of synchronization. You could use a [synchronized set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29) to store blocked hosts. This still wouldn't solve the problem that it takes some time until any connection error is actually detected.

---

Regarding the update: As said in the comments the Future timeout should be larger than the request timeout. Otherwise the Callable might be canceled and the host won't be added to the list. You probably don't even need a timeout when using Future.get because the request will eventually succeed or fail.

The actual problem why you see many exceptions when host A goes down could simply be that many thread are still waiting for the response of host A. You only check for blocked hosts before starting a request, not during any requests. Any thread still waiting for a response from that host will continue to do so until the the timeout is reached.

If you want to prevent this you could try to periodically check if the current host isn't blocked yet. This is a very naive solution and kind of defeats the purpose of futures since it's basically polling. It should help understanding the general problem though.

```
// bad pseudo code 

DataTask dataTask = new DataTask(dataKeys, restTemplate);
future = service.submit(dataTask);

while(!future.isDone()) {
    if( blockedHosts.contains(currentHost) ) {
        // host unreachable, don't wait for http timeout
        future.cancel(); 
    }
    thread.sleep(/* */);
}
```

A better way would be to send an interrupt to all DataTask threads that are waiting for the same hosts when it goes down, so they can abort the request and try the next host.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Appreciated your help. I agree that in my case, making blockHost call atomic doesn't make sense since there will be small span of time in which I won't be able to prevent this. But one problem I am seeing with the above code is (I have above code running in production for a while), as soon as `hostA` goes down, I start seeing lot of `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` on my client as you can see I am using `Callable` so which means I am doing `future.get` somewhere and it throws `TimeoutException` as soon as any hosts goes down

Comment: .. but if all the hosts are up then everything works like a charm without any `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` which makes me think that something is wrong when any host goes down and gets added to block list.

Comment: @Webby I guess when a host goes down while multiple threads are connected, you could expect multiple `RestClientException`. A `TimeoutException` indicates that the callable doesn't return in time though. Could it be that you have set a timeout for `Future.get`, and no timeout (or a longer one) for the http request? If the future has a timeout that is shorter than the http timeout, the callable will be canceled before the unreachable host can be added to the list.

Comment: Yes I have a timeout value for `future.get` but no timeout for `http request` as I am using the default way of executing the url. That might be a good point regarding timeout for future vs http timeout. Not sure what is the default timeout for http request. I have updated the question to give you the better understanding of the code flow just to make sure you have understand correctly what I was saying earlier. You can go through and see whether you understand exactly as I said? Thanks for the help..

Comment: @Webby I don't had much time right now but I've updated my answer. I hope it helps. The question got quite long now, if there are further issues you probably should create a new question and narrow down the problem so more people can help.

Answer (score 1):

The atomicity of your operation doesn’t change when you put the `ConcurrentHashMap` into an `AtomicReference`. `put` and `get` are atomic anyway and the only affected operation, `replaceBlockedHosts`, would work with a simple `volatile` reference as well. But I don’t know why you need this though.

---

What you have within your `call()` method is a *check-then-act* pattern:

First, you call `ClientData.isHostBlocked(hostname)`
then you call `restTemplate.getForObject(generateURL(hostname), …)`.

So the atomicity of `blockHost` and `isHostBlocked` does prevent a thread from being right after the `isHostBlocked` call when another thread calls `blockHost`. Therefore the former would still proceed with the network operation after the latter has added the host to the block list.

---

If you want to limit the number of threads that may fail at the same host, you must limit the number of threads accessing the same host. There’s no way around it.

Comment: Thank a lot for your suggestion. Yeah I agree with your point regarding two threads now. I have this code running for a while in production and I am seeing very weird thing - When all the servers are up `(A,B,C,D as an example)` above code works fine and I don't see any `TimeoutException` happening at all from the `future.get` but if let's say one server `(A)` went down which I was supposed to make a call from the main thread then I start seeing lot of `TimeoutException`, by lot I mean, huge number of client timeouts happening. And I am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: ..In general this won't be happening right since as soon as the server goes down, it will get added to `blockList` and then no thread will be making a call to that server (after few milliseconds), instead it will try another server in the list? So it should be smooth process and then as soon as those servers are up, blockList will get updated from the background thread and then you can start making a call.

Comment: .. I had the same discussion with `kapep` and he is saying that it might be timeout value for future.get is smalled than http request timeout value and because of that it is happening.